# Validate unique field using Ajax, Yii2 ActiveForm

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to Yii, and cannot figure out how ajax validation works with `ActiveForm`. 
In my model I have unique field:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
             //...
            [['end_date'], 'unique'], //ajax is not working 

            [   'end_date', //ajax is working
                'compare',
                'compareAttribute'=>'start_date',
                'operator'=>'>=',  
                'skipOnEmpty'=>true,
                'message'=>'{attribute} must be greater or equal to "{compareValue}".'
            ],
        ];
    }
```

The compare rule is validated with ajax and works fine, but `unique` is not. I tried to enable ajax validation on form:

```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin( ['id' => 'routingForm', 'enableClientValidation' => true, 'enableAjaxValidation' => true]); ?>
```

But don't know what to do next.

Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Routing();
    $cities = [];     
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {            
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'cities' => $cities
        ]);
    }
}
```

I know I could make ajax call to controller on `end_date` change event and form `submit`, but not sure how make all appropriate css to show the errors.

Comment: show your controller code please...

Comment: Just read the official docs, it's covered [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ajax-validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Yii::$app->request->isAjax` in controller.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
      }
   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
       return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
          'model' => $model,
          'cities' => $cities
        ]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your controller...

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Routing();
    $cities = []; 

    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
        return Json::encode(\yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model));
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())  {            
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
   } else {
    return $this->renderAjax('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'cities' => $cities
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: You should not use `Json::encode `, either change response format on the fly or use `ContentNegotiator`.